# Sass command stopped working

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I am having a problem with sass today, any sass related command I type in the command line does not work, it outputs 'sass is not recognized....', even sass -v. It worked fine a couple of days ago. I also went into the ruby folder and there I found a "Start Command Prompt with Ruby" and checking sass there works but not on the normal command line. I also installed Python recently, maybe there is a conflict with that, that I am not aware. If anyone can shed some knowledge or have an idea how to fix this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it? gem install sass

Comment: I haven't, does re-installing sass cause issues with ruby? also I just tried ruby -v and it also says 'ruby is not recognized..'. Maybe the issue is with ruby or this could be a path issue?

Comment: Python should not have an influence on Ruby or sass. Look at your $PATH if `ruby` is not working, try to resolve your problems with `sass` later, either with `bundle show sass` if you use `bundler` or with `gem list sass` otherwise. However, both of these will rely on a working `ruby`on your `$PATH`.

Comment: I checked PATH and ruby was not in there. I had to set it again and sass now works again! Thank you so much for your help! I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @Patru, you should repost as an answer so this can be accepted and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ruby` is not working you should check out your `$PATH` environment variable.

Try to resolve your problems with `sass` later, either with

```
bundle show sass
```

if you use `bundler` or with

```
gem list sass
```

otherwise. However, both of these will rely on a working `ruby` in your `$PATH`.